# Is PHP required for Facebook apps?

Tags: php, facebook, gwt, iframe

I have written a small web app with GWT and am looking into what it will take to make a "clone" of it on Facebook (as a FB app). After spending some time reading the dev docs it looks like a Facebook App is just a vanity canvas that points to another URL under the hood (via `iframe`).

All of the FB dev docs keep re-emphasizing PHP-centric development. Not that I have anything against PHP (!), it's just that I'd like to be able to point the FB app at my (existing) web app main screen and not have to re-write any code.

So... my question boils down to this: **can I just `iframe` the FB app's canvas to my existing web app or do I have to totally re-write my app in PHP?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Afaik the APIs are REST based, there are a couple of SDKs that act as wrappers, but besides that it should be pretty much language agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, it's just an IFrame, Facebook doesn't know what language you use. So you can use anything, although it has to support certain things like URL parameters.

The reason for the PHP documentation is because there is an an official PHP SDK, but no others in that area (There is a JS and smart phone SDK too), all other SDKs are third party.